# Unable to read JSON in AngularJS $http from URL on local server

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-http

I'm working on my first AngularJS app, and for my data I'm trying to read from a page in Drupal website on my local machine. It's running on Apache, and it's accessible from an alias URL (i.e. http://mylocalsite instead of http://localhost/mylocalsite). The page displays nothing but a JSON array of data, but for some reason, my Angular app is unable to read it using $http, either

```
angular.module('nbd7AppApp')
  .controller('BlogListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://mylocalsite/blogs/json'})
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.nodes = data;
    });
  }]);
```

or

```
angular.module('nbd7AppApp')
  .controller('BlogListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://mylocalsite/blogs/json'})
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.nodes = data;
    });
  }]);
```

However, if I put the JSON into a local file and access it like so

```
angular.module('nbd7AppApp')
  .controller('BlogListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('views/blogs.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.nodes = data;
    });
  }]);
```

it works perfectly. Is there something I need to do differently to be able to read it from the site URL?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: If you show the Chrome debugger on the page for your angular app, does the body of the http request that you see in the network tab look identical to what's in the local JSON file? Also is the character encoding set to UTF8 on the server that you're getting the JSON from?

Comment: Is the `blogs/json` part of the alias? I mean, does translate it to `blogs.json`?

Comment: Oh, yeah, the console. Yes it gives me an this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mylocalsite/blogs/json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. I'm running the angular app on a separate port from the one the site is on.

Comment: you can add a white list for cross site access in angular. By default javascript can only access same domain for security purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by my comment above, the answer was [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html). Once I added this line to my Apache virtual host:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

the error went away.